# ordering facet_wrap levels by frequency

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, facet-wrap, waffle-chart

I'm trying to do a waffle chart for the championships won by F1 drivers so far. The chart comes out good but it comes out with alphabetical labels. I want it to start from the most titles won to the least.

I've tried ***ordering*** and ***fct_relevel***. But nothing works. Below is the code

```
ggplot(data = dfc, aes(fill=Champions, values=one)) +
  geom_waffle(color = "cornsilk", size=0.25, n_rows=7)+
  facet_wrap(~Champions, nrow = 3, strip.position = "bottom",labeller = label_wrap_gen(6))
```

And this is the
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IyZi.png) I'm looking for.

You can find the entire code [here](https://github.com/rpavan07/TidyTuesday/blob/main/2021_Week37/f1.R)

The dataset looks like

```
Season    Champions    Team   one
1              a           x     1
2              a           x     1
3              b           y     1
4              a           x     1
5              c           z     1
```

Comment: `Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: \`Champions\``. (It is not in your sample data.)

Comment: @r2evans sorry, my bad. just edited it

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you tried using `fct_reorder`?

Comment: @RichardTelford yeah, tried that as well. Didn't work, but the answer worked (fct_infreq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using `forcats` (also part of the `tidyverse` package).

`fct_infreq()` orders factors according to their frequency in the data, and you can use that to specify the ordering of the levels in your data.

```
dfc$Champions <- factor(dfc$Champions, levels=levels(fct_infreq(dfc$Champions)))

ggplot(data = dfc, aes(fill=Champions, values=one)) +
  geom_waffle(color = "cornsilk", size=0.25, n_rows=7) +
  facet_wrap(~Champions, nrow = 3, strip.position = "bottom", labeller = label_wrap_gen(6))
```